# Windows is stuck on black screen with command line cursor

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

So yesterday I left laptop to update at night. When I woke up and tried to boot it the PC went into a bootloop of some sort showing me only the manufacturer logo each start. After many tries to boot it finally stopped the loop and got stuck on a black command line screen. Not in Windows, it seems like Windows could not boot at all. I also have Ubuntu on PC and the bootloader should be grub but it never asked me which OS to start.

So I simply pressed update and restart and this where it led me. Any ideas on what's going on and how to fix this?

Comment: I'd restore from my last disk image, assuming you can get to BIOS.UEFI.,

Answer (score 0):

I had Ubuntu installed on my laptop alongside Windows 10 which resulted in Grub being my main bootloader. For some reason the update of win 10 removed grub or broke it somehow. I didn't really know how to fix it, liveusb didn't help me either so I completely reinstalled Ubuntu on the same drive overriding previous one(thanks to I haven't had anything important there) which reinstalled Grub and I finally was able to boot Windows 10 again.

This question is closed.